# Excel генерация упорядоченного списка из часов и минут случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне не повторяющих друг друга в целом

Tags: excel, сортировка, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Есть определённое количество сообщений, например 30 штук точка их нужно разослать в течение дня точка разбить до конца этого дня то есть до 23:59
Есть текущее время. Например, 6:05 утра.
Нужно нагенерить последовательное случайные числа в виде часов и минут.
Так чтобы каждое следующая ячейка, что идёт ниже по последовательности была больше предыдущей. Но предыдущее не была больше следующей.
В одной колонне часы в другой минуты.

Нужно сделать так чтобы для других 30 или другого количества сообщений генерирует в другое время в диапазоне от текущего времени до конца этого дня.

Пример ниже:

порядковый номер|часы|минуты
1    6 34
2    8 49
3    8 56
4    9 19
5    12 56
6    14 20
....
....
30  22 40

Как видно часы могут повторяться, минуты тоже, если отдельно, но суммарно нет.
Для значения из 30 сортируется на оставшиеся день на 30 позиции.
Если значение 2, то может быть примерно так:

порядковый номер|часы|минуты
1 8 40
2 20 34

Чтобы каждый раз не сортировать в Excel в ручную, как задать формулу или другим способом генерить данные числа

были использованы функции в excel
=NOW()
=HOUR(S6)
=MINUTE(S6)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Писать надо так, чтобы понимали те, кто впервые видит Вашу таблицу.  Переводить Вашу строку *номер|часы|минуты* в вертикальную таблицу? Юленька, сначала помогите себе сами - отредактируйте текст сообщения  и прикрепите ссылку на живую таблицу, где будет пример правильного результата.

Answer (score 1):

Решение может быть таким:

1. Не нужно генерировать отдельно часы отдельно минуты. Нужно сгенерировать необходимое количество моментов времени "=INT(NOW())+RAND()".
2. Потом получившиеся значения отсортировать по возрастанию.
3. Для генерации от текущего времени использовать формулу "=INT(NOW())+$A$1+ RAND()*(1-$A$1)", где "[$A$1]=NOW()-INT(NOW())" (ячейка "$A$1" взята для примера).

Это можно сделать как в таблице (вручную), так и на VBA. В таблице нужно размножить формулу на небходимое количество ячеек, скопировать их и вставить *в другое место только значения*. Потом отсортировать и отформатировать как дату/время.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]